# Link between measure and measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question

A measure is defined by the relations between sets in the codomain and algebraic operations in the domain $\mathbb R^+$ (I think of the additivity requirement here), while a measurable function is defined on how the preimages of $\sigma$-algebra elements in the domain are included in the $\sigma$-algebra elements of the codomain. So a link between the two concepts is not obvious (to me, at least).

In the particular case of measurable functions $(\Omega, \mathcal A) \to (\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R^+))$, is there a link between measures and measurable functions ? Cases when one imply the other for example ?

Comment: You can push measures along measurable functions: Given a measurable $f \colon (X, \mathcal A) \to (Y, \mathcal B)$ and a measure $\mu\colon \mathcal A \to [0, \infty)$ on $X$, $f_*\mu \colon \mathcal B \to [0, \infty)$ defined by $(f_*\mu)(B) := \mu(f^{-1}[B])$ is a measure on $Y$.

Comment: Measures aren't strictly only for the codomain. In order to integrate real-valued measurable functions, one also needs a measure on the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right --- conceptually a measure and a measurable function can be defined without each other. It seems to me a measurable function directly describes the mapping between two  measurable spaces, without the need for a measure on both ends. But both measures and measurable functions are needed when defining an integral.